# Slow animation with Nannou

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust and Nannou, and I'm confused why this animation is so slow with only 1000 elements. I was hoping generating animations in Rust would be lighting fast, but not off to a great start.

```rust
use nannou::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    nannou::app(model).update(update).simple_window(view).run();
}

struct Model {
    particles: Vec<f32>,
}

fn model(_app: &App) -> Model {
    let n_particles = 1000;
    let mut particles: Vec<f32> = vec![];

    for idx in 0..n_particles {
        particles.push(map_range(idx, 0, n_particles, 0.0, 1.0));
    }
    Model { particles }
}

fn update(_app: &App, model: &mut Model, _update: Update) {}

fn view(app: &App, model: &Model, frame: Frame) {
    // Prepare to draw.
    let draw = app.draw();
    // Get boundary of the window (to constrain the movements of our circle)
    let boundary = app.window_rect();
    // Clear the background to purple.
    draw.background().color(PLUM);
    for idx in 0..model.particles.len() {
        let particle = &model.particles[idx];

        let sine = app.time.sin() * particle;
        let slowersine = (app.time / 2.0).sin() * particle;

        // Map the sine wave functions to ranges between the boundaries of the window
        let x = map_range(sine, -1.0, 1.0, boundary.left(), boundary.right());
        let y = map_range(slowersine, -1.0, 1.0, boundary.bottom(), boundary.top());

        // Draw a blue ellipse at the x/y coordinates 0.0, 0.0
        draw.ellipse().color(STEELBLUE).x_y(x, y).radius(10.0);
    }
    // Generate sine wave data based on the time of the app

    draw.to_frame(app, &frame).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Are you running in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your code is doing what you are expecting.  The use of "particle" in the view function seems superfluous when it is ultimately only being used to affect the x and y values passed to the x_y function.

Running your code as-is gave me an unexpected result:  It looked like the ellipse was rendered multiple times creating an animated line waving around the screen.  Commenting out several lines and removing "* particle" from the "sine" and "slowersine" assignments resulted in an ellipse moving around the window smoothly.

Note:  Several warnings are generated due to unused variables now.

Updated code:

```
use nannou::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    nannou::app(model).update(update).simple_window(view).run();
}

struct Model {
    particles: Vec<f32>,
}

fn model(_app: &App) -> Model {
    let n_particles = 1000;
    let mut particles: Vec<f32> = vec![];

    for idx in 0..n_particles {
        particles.push(map_range(idx, 0, n_particles, 0.0, 1.0));
    }
    Model { particles }
}

fn update(_app: &App, model: &mut Model, _update: Update) {}

fn view(app: &App, model: &Model, frame: Frame) {
    // Prepare to draw.
    let draw = app.draw();
    // Get boundary of the window (to constrain the movements of our circle)
    let boundary = app.window_rect();
    // Clear the background to purple.
    draw.background().color(PLUM);
//    for idx in 0..model.particles.len() {
//        let particle = &model.particles[idx];

//        let sine = app.time.sin() * particle;
//        let slowersine = (app.time / 2.0).sin() * particle;
        let sine = app.time.sin();
        let slowersine = (app.time / 2.0).sin();

        // Map the sine wave functions to ranges between the boundaries of the window
        let x = map_range(sine, -1.0, 1.0, boundary.left(), boundary.right());
        let y = map_range(slowersine, -1.0, 1.0, boundary.bottom(), boundary.top());

        // Draw a blue ellipse at the x/y coordinates 0.0, 0.0
        draw.ellipse().color(STEELBLUE).x_y(x, y).radius(10.0);
//    }
    // Generate sine wave data based on the time of the app

    draw.to_frame(app, &frame).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Your code produces a single circle right? I'm trying to animate with 1000's of circles

Comment: Yeah, my update changed the code to show one single circle moving around.  If I get some time tomorrow, I will take another look at the code now that I understand more of what you are doing.